# Adding a an object as a member variable to a new Class in run time in Java

Tags: java

Have this requirement where i am getting the classes names at run time from a particular package . I dont know the classes before hand

```
List<Class<?>> classes = PlayGround.find("MyOwn.newpackage");
```

Now i need to instantiate a new Object for each class in the above list and add it as members in another class (say Class Model)

```
 for (int i=0;i<classes.size();i++){

    Class tmp = classes.get(i);

    }
```

is possible to create a object from the above tmp class and add it as member variable for Class Model in real time in Java?

The not so clean way would be to edit the .java filestream but was wondering can i do it from program itself.

Comment: temp = new class();       ...?

Comment: @RuchirBaonia, could you please elaborate a bit , maybe i missed something ?, how would this help to add the object as a member variable to another class?.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [`Constructor#newInstance(Object...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-). This is preferable to `Class#newInstance` because the latter will propagate any exception thrown by the no-args constructor, even if it is a checked one. This means that you don't get any of the compile-time type-checks for checked exception. `Constructor#newInstance` by contrast will throw an `InvocationTargetException` that wraps the checked exception thrown by the constructor.

So what you want to do is the following (exception-handling omitted for brevity):

```
Constructor<?> constructor = tmp.getConstructor();
```

Now you can create a new instance by calling `constructor.newInstance()`. As far as "adding it as a member variable to another class", why do you need to do that? It would be much easier for the target class to have a list of some sort and then you can just insert the new instance into that list. Or, if you know exactly what type of object the target class needs, create member variables beforehand, and then you can just provide it directly (through a constructor or through a setter).

Answer (score 0):

we can use **class.forName()** which is used for loading the class dynamically at run time.
eg:
**class.forName(name of the class to be loaded)**
if you want to create object for the loaded class you can use **new instance()**.
eg:
**Class.forName("Employee").newInstance()** you will get object of employee.
in this way we can load class dynamically and create object of that loaded class at runtime.

In your case you can traverse through the list and load the class and instantiate object for those loaded class and use it as per your requirement.

Comment: yes ofcourse list has a set of classes here requirement is we need to instantiate those right?

Comment: Thanks @Madhesh, yes .newInstance() will help to initialise objects but i need to take these objects and add it as member variables into another class. Searched for solutions but all point to loading the .java files and editing it...

Comment: after instantaite the objects store those objects in to a list,pass that list to the class where you want to set these objects as members.then you get the objects from the list and assign to its members.